# How to create a Samsung Galaxy Note emulator in the Android AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to create a Samsung Galaxy Note (version 2.3.6) virtual device within the AVD manager with 800*1280 resolution.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can create an emulator with version 2.3.6, but you can make one with
version 2.3.3 and screen size 800 * 600.

go to AVD Manager> New... and fill the screen as followed:
Name : galaxyNote
Target : Android 2.3.3 - API Level 10
SD Card : 256 MiB
Skin : 800 * 1280

then click on create AVD. done.

Comment: many things are broken in 2.3.3, so testing your code against 2.3.3 when users have 2.3.6 is unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

Skin: (800x1200 + density 320)

Answer (score 1):

In case this is useful...
According to Samsung, the display for the Note II is as follows:
please note that the density value is an important factor and should also be set in the emulator configuration

- heightPixels=1280
- widthpPixels=720
- densityDpi = 320 ("Abstracted LCD density")

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/emulator-size-for-galaxy-note-2-/77/178557

For reference, the pixel densities for these are:

```
ldpi  | mdpi  | tvdpi  | hdpi  | xhdpi  | xxhdpi
120   | 160   | 213    | 240   | 320    | 480
```

I copied the above from this link that has a bunch of other good info
[About Android image and asset sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581649/about-android-image-size-and-assets-sizes)

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action

Enjoi :)

This is site to use emulator for 30 minutes-2 hours of time

Comment: page not found bro