# About Android image and asset sizes

Tags: android, android-resources, android-image, android-screen-support

I need to clarify some doubt about the image assets  for my app,

if I specify in an xml file that the height of something [image view] is 50 dip height

which type of screen should  i choose from the resources folder?

```
drawable, hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi,
```

to have the 50 px height image,

and what is the percentage for bigger, smaller size images compared to the base image,

like in iOS, @2x, is literally 2 times the size of the image, and you say programatically the normal size,

thanks!

Comment: Your question is explained in Android's manual: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 376, accepted):

`mdpi` is the reference density -- that is, 1 px on an `mdpi` display is equal to 1 dip. The ratio for asset scaling is:

```
ldpi | mdpi | tvdpi | hdpi | xhdpi | xxhdpi | xxxhdpi
0.75 | 1    | 1.33  | 1.5  | 2     | 3      | 4
```

Although you don't really need to worry about `tvdpi` unless you're developing specifically for Google TV or the original Nexus 7 -- but even Google recommends simply using `hdpi` assets.

What this means is if you're doing a 48dip image and plan to support up to `xxhdpi resolution`, you should start with a 144px image (192px if you want native assets for xxxhdpi) and make the following images for the densities:

```
ldpi    | mdpi    | tvdpi    | hdpi    | xhdpi     | xxhdpi    | xxxhdpi
36 x 36 | 48 x 48 | 64 x 64  | 72 x 72 | 96 x 96   | 144 x 144 | 192 x 192
```

And these should display at roughly the same size on any device, provided you've placed these in density-specific folders (e.g. `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, etc.)

For reference, the pixel densities for these are:

```
ldpi  | mdpi  | tvdpi  | hdpi  | xhdpi  | xxhdpi  | xxxhdpi
120   | 160   | 213    | 240   | 320    | 480     | 640
```

Comment: How do you decide you have to start from a 48dip ? Say you only have a tablet (mdpi) at hand, do you start with a random size, and iterate until it looks "big enough" ?

Comment: @phtrivier It's just a size I used as an example. In this case, it's the size of a launcher icon. Whatever size you need for other assets depends on your use case.

Comment: Best explanation. I also use this site for conversion regards px and dp. https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/

Comment: what last part of you answer meanings? ldpi 120 ? where this number came from?

Comment: @phtrivier It might be helpful to note that ```1 inch = 160dip```, so you can figure out what size you'd like your image to appear on a device in inches first, use this to convert to ```dip``` and then convert to the image sizes you may need.

Comment: I also made a tool to calculate this on the fly: https://pixit-tool.web.app/#/

Answer (score 23):

Based on **kcoppock**'s answer I have created the following shell script to automatically resize all images to the correct size and copy them in the respective Android drawable-* - folders!

Create a shell script and paste the following code:

**createAndroidImages.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter the subfolder of the original images? " folder
read -p "How many DP (width) should the image have? " dp

for i in $(find $folder/. -type f -name "*[A-Z]*"); do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | tr A-Z a-z)"; done

mkdir drawable-ldpi
mkdir drawable-mdpi
mkdir drawable-tvdpi
mkdir drawable-hdpi
mkdir drawable-xhdpi
mkdir drawable-xxhdpi
mkdir drawable-xxxhdpi

cp $folder/* drawable-ldpi/
cp $folder/* drawable-mdpi/
cp $folder/* drawable-tvdpi/
cp $folder/* drawable-hdpi/
cp $folder/* drawable-xhdpi/
cp $folder/* drawable-xxhdpi/
cp $folder/* drawable-xxxhdpi/

sips -Z $(echo $dp*3/4 | bc) drawable-ldpi/*
sips -Z $(echo $dp | bc) drawable-mdpi/*
sips -Z $(echo $dp*4/3 | bc) drawable-tvdpi/*
sips -Z $(echo $dp*3/2 | bc) drawable-hdpi/*
sips -Z $(echo $dp*2 | bc) drawable-xhdpi/*
sips -Z $(echo $dp*3 | bc) drawable-xxhdpi/*
sips -Z $(echo $dp*4 | bc) drawable-xxxhdpi/*
```

Put your script in a folder and your original images in a subfolder e.g.:

```
/
.. createAndroidImages.sh
.. originalImages/
....a123.png
....b456.png
```

Run the shell script in terminal: `sh createAndroidImages.sh`

To copy the created images directly to your Android Studio Project:

```
cp -R drawable-* ~/AndroidStudioProjects/ESCRating/app/src/main/res/
```

You're done! Hope this helps someone!

P.S. Please note that the original images should have at least four times the width in pixels, than the desired width in dpi (e.g. 4 (factor xxxhdpi) * 30dpi => 120px) for optimal results.

Answer (score 4):

kcoppock did a great job explaining Andorid screen densities.
I just would like to add one more point regarding the original question.

**Android Tablet launcher icon uses one density bucket up.**

According to Google's developer Nick Butcher's Google+ post

> The gorgeous screen on the Nexus 10 falls into the XHDPI density bucket.  On tablets, Launcher uses icons from one density bucket up [0] to render them slightly larger.  To ensure that your launcher icon (arguably your apps most important asset) is crisp you need to add a 144*144px icon in the drawable-xxhdpi or drawable-480dpi folder.

Find source [here](https://plus.google.com/+NickButcher/posts/ePQya3KsTjW)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my calculations for upscaling and scaling down of images for android-

ldpi (120 dpi, Low density screen) - 36px x 36px **(0.19) (1)**

mdpi (160 dpi, Medium density screen) - 48px x 48px **(0.25) (1.33)**

hdpi (240 dpi, High density screen) - 72px x 72px **(0.38) (2)**

xhdpi (320 dpi, Extra-high density screen) - 96px x 96px **(0.5) (2.67)**

xxhdpi (480 dpi, Extra-extra-high density screen) - 144px x 144px **(0.75) (4)**

xxxhdpi (640 dpi, Extra-extra-extra-high density screen) - 192px x 192px **(1.0) (5.33)**

[My short article](http://www.vishalkumarsahu.in/blog/windows-script-to-create-all-image-assets-for-android-and-ios-app/) is helpful to create image resources using imagemagick, when there are multiple images.