# Android Icon Sizes

Tags: android

I know there are guidelines for creating icons for specific areas in Android (Tab, List, etc.) and how you would size them according to ldpi, mdpi, hdpi etc.

Are there any rules on how to scale other in-app icons?

I've got a 'tiny' icon of 10x10 px which I am using on my mdpi dev phone, what would be the scaling rules to create ldpi, hdpi & xhdpi versions of that icon?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11581786/321697) may answer your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ratios are .75|1|1.33|1.5|2.|3.|4. (or 3:4:6:8:12:16) That is, for your 10x10px bitmap, the graphics would be

```
ldpi    - 10x10 * 0.75 = 7x7
mdpi    - 10x10 * 1    = 10x10
tvdpi   - 10x10 * 1.33 = 13x13
hdpi    - 10x10 * 1.5  = 15x15
xhdpi   - 10x10 * 2    = 20x20
xxhdpi  - 10x10 * 3    = 30x30
xxxhdpi - 10x10 * 4    = 40x40
```

Comment: Also to note, the recommendation is to make your graphic dimensions divisible by four for better scaling. For example, if your 10x10 graphic was instead 12x12, it would scale to ldpi, hdpi, and xhdpi without fractional pixel dimensions. (9x9, 18x18, and 24x24, respectively).

Comment: Just looked closely at your ratios -- it should be `.75|1|1.33|1.5|2`, not `.75|1|1.33|2|4`.

Comment: Thanks to DeeV and kcoppock, both. I'll resize my base icon to be 12*12 (divisible by 4) and then apply the ratios.

Comment: Where is that ratio info, by the way?

Comment: It's scattered around the "Supporing Multiple Screen" page. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#Alternative

Comment: Mainly, look at the "Alternative drawables" section.  Also, by design, ldpi is 120dpi (120/160 = .75); mdpi is 160dpi (160/160 = 1); hdpi is 240dpi (240/160 = 1.5); and xhdpi is 320dpi (320/160 = 2)

Comment: You can get different size for icons :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dsquareinfoways.iconsizegenerator&hl=en

Answer (score 13):

I would create separate images for each one:

```
Res     Px     
ldpi    36 x 36
mdpi    48 x 48
hdpi    72 x 72
xhdpi   96 x 96
xxhdpi  144x144
xxxhdpi 192x192
```

Then just put each of them in the separate stalks of the drawable folder.

Comment: For xxhdpi it is 180x180 and xxxhdpi is 192x192 according to Google's documentation here, http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html. Search on the page for, "180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density". I use them in Export to Multiple Sizes Photoshop script here, http://www.velara3.com.

Comment: @1.21 According to both your own link and the following one, xxhdpi is indeed 144x144 https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html. Also, it doesn't make sense that xxhdpi would be 180 and xxxhdpi would be 192, since it's supposed to be a 3:4 ratio, which would would make xxx 240x240.

Comment: They've changed the documentation since I made my comment. Look at the way back machine

Answer (score 2):

Generalized rule for pixel values to support multiple screen is based on a baseline configuration of your device screen density. Baseline for density 160 pixels , mdpi comes in this range. So by calculating dpi values you can put these values in different dimens.xml to support various devices. General formula is :

Result = Value(dpi) * device density(pi)/160(dpi)

So first check your device density first then according to above formula calculate the values for dimens.xml. For standard we generally assume that:

For mdpi density = 160, hdpi - 240, xhdpi - 320 , ldpi - 120

As in your case if value is 10*10 then the Result for different screen will be :

For ldpi:

Result = 10*120/160 = 7.5 , i.e 7 pixels

For mdpi:

Result = 10*160/160 = 10 pixels

For hdpi:

Result = 10*240/160 = 15 pixels

For xhdpi:

Result = 10*320/160 = 20 pixels

You can also refer to this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html  and http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the Android-Iconography guide, the icons should follow  **2:3:4:6 scale ratios** for different screen densities, **medium, high, x-high, and xx-high** respectively.

[image]

You can also check Android Design guide for iconography. http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html