# Minimal icon size for android

Tags: android, icons, size, favicon

What is a minimal image size that can be used as icon ? I'm trying to optimize my application and icon takes a lot of space in apk file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12117023/1777090

Comment: @ Pan are you asking size in terms of pixel width and height or size in terms of KB ?

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ thx,but I mean in KB

Comment: @PanBydlak: there is no limitation in terms of KB. Please check quality of images also , while you are optimizing the application. You can use .png images with 18 or 24 bit images.