# How do I prepare images for all the Android resolutions?

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-image

In iOS preparing graphics is simple. There are either a normal image (height x width) or a retina image which is @2x (2 times height x 2 times width).

However, since I'm new to Android, I see a ton of drawable-* folders in Eclipse where the * can be "hdpi" or "ldpi" or "mdpi" or "xhdpi" or "xxhdpi". Can someone very clearly and simply list for me what I must do to satisfy each of the display possibilities so my images will look right in each instance? I'm envisioning an answer will be a bullet list with each "*" listed and a sub-bullet list including the things that must be done.

I'd also really enjoy an answer that would start with the highest density and greatest dimension image and working down since I'll be creating in Photoshop and will be reducing quality from a master image.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence. Check the documentation. Read the doc completely.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: This [chart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11581786/321697) should help too.

Comment: check out this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-devices

Answer (score 31):

i got this off of this site a while back, it still comes in handy

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
Generalised Dpi values for screens:

ldpi Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi)
mdpi Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
hdpi Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
Therefore generalised size of your resources (assuming they are full screen):

ldpi
Vertical = 426 * 120 / 160 = 319.5px
Horizontal = 320 * 120 / 160 = 240px
mdpi
Vertical = 470 * 160 / 160 = 470px
Horizontal = 320 * 160 / 160 = 320px
hdpi
Vertical = 640 * 240 / 160 = 960px
Horizontal = 480 * 240 / 160 = 720px
xhdpi
Vertical = 960 * 320 / 160 = 1920px
Horizontal = 720 * 320 / 160 = 1440px

px = dp*dpi/160
```

Answer (score 8):

In Android Studio just go to `File -> New -> Image Asset` and create your images right out of the IDE.

Comment: I can only find an option to create Icons.
How do I import any image to be used in the project?

Answer (score 7):

On Android we usually handle image sizes in units of "dp" or "dip" which stands for device independent pixel. 1 dip = 1 pixel, on a mdpi screen. There are loads of devices out there with different screen densities, not just normal and retina, so there are multiple DPI buckets a device's screen may fall into:

- ldpi (low dpi): around 120 dpi
- mdpi (medium dpi): around 160 dpi
- hdpi (high dpi): around 240 dpi
- xhdpi (xtra high dpi): around 320 dpi

Note that these are buckets, so a device with a 170 dpi screen will count as an mdpi device.

Let's say that you have a vector based image in PS and you need to create an image resource for Android and you'd like to support all these screen densities. Let's say that image needs to be 100x100 dip large. So you create a 100x100 pixel version for mdpi, a 150x150 pixel version for hdpi, 200x200 for xhdpi, and 75x75 for ldpi. You can think of "mdpi - xhdpi" on Android as "normal - retina" on iOS.

As for the larges image size that you can use, I really can't say. There's no hard limit as far as I know, but the device obviously won't be able to load a 20000x20000 bitmap into memory without downsampling because of heap limits.

Comment: Some more explanation:The larger the screen are, and the better resolution they have, thhe  the higher is the dp measurement. Some screen of the same size have different number of pixels, that is a different dpi also. So they  need a different resource ( the high resolution one with more pixels obviously).

Answer (score 6):

There is an online tool for that [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)
And also there is File|New|Android Icon Set in Eclipse

Comment: Aren't these files are too small for representation of the image on mobile devices? Isn't it only for the Icon?

Comment: Updated the link. Not sure if it's an official tool or not. AS itself has a similar built-in tool for that now.

Comment: The AS tool is meant for icon size image, so it's pretty limiting.