# How to optimize app size for different screen resolutions in Android?

Tags: android, optimization, screen

When I put different image sizes for different screen sizes the overall app size increases dramatically.

ldpi 15kb
mdpi 20kb
hdpi 25kb 
...
= 150kb

I'm not sure how the system works, does the user download all of the images and then use the one that fits its device and delete the rest?

And what is a good solution to optimize the app size for different screens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [about android image size and assets sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581649/about-android-image-size-and-assets-sizes)

Comment: I think my question isn't clear enough, I want to know how the app screen size optimization works, when I put 5 different sized images, 4 of them are useless for any device and this increases the app size. So does the device delete the useless image sizes after download? If so, why does it download all those unused images in the first place? Is there a good way to optimize this?

Comment: @demirb if you think you're question isn't clear enough then **edit it** to make it clearer.

Comment: @ChrisF nah turns out droiddev didnt understand it, pratts answer was what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application size is increased due to different sizes images, I would suggest you to use **9 patch** images whenever you could use throughout the application.

Another solution is, if you application supports client-server communication then ask to server for application images and download all app images from there and then set it up dynamically.

Remove extra classes, images, assets etc to reduce your app size.

Do Database operation with optimize manner, remove old entries from DB on timely basis.