# How to support 4K vs HD backgrounds in drawable resources?

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm making a Splash activity for when the app launches for Android TV. The splash activity has a background set in the theme as windowBackground. The app supports 4K content, so I would like the Splash background to be in 4K for 4K screens, and HD for HD screens, but I don't know how distinguish them in the drawable-XXX resource folders since you can't target pixels and I'm not sure how Android TV distinguishes dps for different TVs since they should all be tvdpi. The Activity will be doing work in the background, so I don't want to just put the 4K image for all devices.

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Have you seen / tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27979314/2644098)?

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy yes I did, but because it's a full-screen background image, dp is irrelevant. I'm targetting pixels. Thanks for the suggestion.