# Multiple screen support for android TV

Tags: android, android-tv, screen-density

I understand the difference between different screen densities (dpi) and dip. While developing an app for android TV, which screen densities should I support? In other words how many versions of the assets do we need to create. Do I need all (mdpi / hdpi / xhpi / xxhdpi / xxxhdpi) Or only the subset for Android TV?

Comment: Well, it always depends on you in which dpi you will use. Another way of determining the correct dpi is based on the screen size that you are using. Check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to know more about on how to support multiple screens in android. For more information, check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978791/which-resource-qualifier-should-i-use-to-support-1080p-720p-android-tv-andro).

Answer (score 1):

In general, `xhdpi` should work for any TV, but you also can use the `television` qualifier to create assets solely for TVs.

Comment: According to Android documention: "Your TV layout should target a screen size of 1920 x 1080 pixels [standard 1080p/HD], and then allow the Android system to downscale your layout elements to 720p if necessary." So xhdpi is a good solution.