# Resource qualifier for 4K (not -xxxxhdpi ?) 807dpi

Tags: android, directory, android-resources, dpi

I'm trying to make a few resource images for 4K.
I have a Sony 4K display Android phone and have noticed a few things off in one of my apps and want to fix it and prepare for the future.

I've tried drawable-xxxxhdpi, but it seems like it's not a valid qualifier name.

*Not looking for a workaround with xxxhdpi or to explain why I want the 4K.
I just want to know what resource folder I can create to set for 4K/807dpi.

Comment: Looking at the official documentation, you can use `tvdpi` as a density identifier or you can use `sw<w>dp` identifier which is the smallest width for which you should use this layout. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27979314/9119277) as well

Comment: Thanks, but I think that only pulls for TVs, and those are for huge screens making for very low dpi.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered I needed to rename drawable-xxxhdpi to drawable-w360dp-xxxhdpi to keep support for 2K then make drawable-sw420dp-xxxhdpi to support 4K separately.