# Layout elements looks blurry on 4K screen Android TV

Tags: android-tv, screen-size, android-screen-support, screensaver, television

I am developing an app for Android TV it is a screensaver app and I just loading a URL in WebView I have used DayDream Service for this purpose everything is fine, I just want to know that how can I make my layout to support 4K resolution, because when I load [http://howbigismybrowser.com/] it shows 960*500 every time no what configuration I am using. I have seen google official doc on the link

[https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes]
also, I have seen this link and implemented the same link
I have tried by making folder configurations like

```
layout-sw320dp

layout-sw600dp

layout-sw720dp
```

[[Which resource qualifier should I use to support 1080p, 720p android TV? - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978791/which-resource-qualifier-should-i-use-to-support-1080p-720p-android-tv-andro/40473641#40473641])

I made subfolder in `res\`folder to support different screen size but am getting same result  [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpze7.png)

Could anyone please help me how can I target a full 4K resolution because right now my Webview looks blurry on 4K TV

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it's possible to target a 4K resolution with your UI components natively. According to the [Android 6.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0#4K-display) around the 4K display mode:

> While in 4K display mode, the UI continues to be rendered at the original resolution (such as 1080p) and is upscaled to 4K, but SurfaceView objects may show content at the native resolution.

I might be mistaken, but I believe the intention here is to allow developers to build their UI for a standard 1080p resolution without having to account for 4K, but this still allows native 4K video as that would be rendered to the SurfaceView.