# Difference between values-swXXXdp and values-swXXXdp-(ldpi,mdpi, hdpi, or xhpdi)?

Tags: android, android-resources

I read Q&A on how to structure the values folder for multiple screens densities  [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21324209/5544859), however I cannot seem to understand what is the difference between these two cases for instance:

**Case 1:**

```
res/values-sw320dp-hdpi/dimens.xml    
res/values-sw320dp-xhdpi/dimens.xml    
res/values-sw320dp-xxhdpi/dimens.xml    
res/values-sw320dp-xxxhdpi/dimens.xml  
res/values-sw480dp-hdpi/dimens.xml    
res/values-sw480dp-xhdpi/dimens.xml    
res/values-sw480dp-xxhdpi/dimens.xml    
res/values-sw480dp-xxxhdpi/dimens.xml

...ect
```

**Case 2:**

```
res/values-sw320dp/dimens.xml     
res/values-sw480dp/dimens.xml    
res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml  
res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml
```

**Question**: How big of a difference does it make to use or not use the suffix `mdpi/hdpi/xhpi/xxhpdi` in folder architecture?

Comment: mdpi usual for low end devices so when you load big pictures it can cause outofmemoryexception, happens to me several times.. this is an example..

Comment: This post will help you better than I could. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581649/about-android-image-and-asset-sizes)

Comment: in the cases listed in my question, I have values-swXXXdp as the first appended suffix. Android validates configuration qualifiers in order of precedence, see here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources  which means it's already separating it based on its smallest width, so what difference does it make to add the second suffix which is mdpi, hdpi, xhpi, or xxhpdi?

Answer (score 0):

In case 2 you only differentiate it based on smallest width so appropriate width resource file is used.

In case 1, When you use *res/values-sw320dp-hdpi* it further get's differentiated based on screen density in this case **hdpi**(240dpi), because minimum 320dp screen's can exist in different density levels.

Comment: Okay, let's say for example we have the Android One device that has 480*854 pixels which is equivalent to 320*569 dp because of its 1.5 hdpi density and also we have the HTC One M8 with 1080*1920 equivalent to 360*640 dp because of its 3 xxhdpi density. They will both fall on the values-sw320dp bucket, so will it make a big difference if they each have their own values-sw320dp-hdpi/dimens.xml  and values-sw320dp-xxhdpi/dimens.xml  respectively?